# Cannot access internet on wireless network bridge, but can access LAN

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, bridge

I have a wireless bridge/wifi repeater that I am trying to use as a bridge.  I have successfully gotten it to work with home network using the a DHCP IP address, but something I cannot reach the internet using an assigned static IP address.  I can however reach all other devices on the subnet.

Wifi bridge used: Vonets VAP11G
Trying to connect: Windows 7 CE device to internet over this wireless connection.
Knowns: Same internet connection works using wifi on laptop, on a static IPv4 address in the same subnet.  Laptop can also reach the wifi bridge via this connection.

Troubleshooting info: I have physically connected the Windows 7 CE device to the local switch, and internet works fine.
I've set the Windows device to DHCP and the bridge to DHCP with assigned IP - no worky worky
I've set Windows static IP to the same as the one on the bridge, - doesn't work
I've set the Windows static IP address to a different one as the bridge, but same subnet.. same results

Edited to add: If I try to ping a known web address such as google 8.8.8.8, I get a result of "Ping: Transmit failed. General Failure"

If you look at the manual for this bridge,.. its really bad, but I figured going through those options something would work.

Suspicion: Perhaps the firewall is somehow blocking the Wifi bridge's access to the internet? .. but if I can connect via ethernet using the same static IP address, that should mean I can do the same via wifi, right? I believe port 80 is the standard for internet traffic, is there a possibility the bridge is trying a different port?

Help!

Comment: The bridge is also giving out DHCP or forwarding the requests to the main device? This sounds like the windows ce device doesn't know the correct gateway address to reach the Internet...

Comment: Not sure why I wasn't notified of your reply... but anyhow.  Thanks for your response.  It has been a few weeks since I've been able to revisit this issue, I will look into the gateway, as I think you might be onto something. To parse your thought: If the bridge is assigning DCHP to the windows CE device, it might be using a different gateway?

Comment: It may be handing out the wrong gateway address (the only way devices know where to send packets that leave your local lan). This should be pretty easy to check.

Comment: Any advice on how? I’m set the static IP and leave the default gateway blank.

Comment: **Ipconfig /all** from windows command prompt while connected to the main ISP router. Use the IP address from the default gateway listed here.